# FileUpload is not uploading all images

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, file-upload

I'm working on a project in which I've to upload multiple files using FileUpload control:

I've a button to save image files as like this:

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (fuImage.HasFiles)
    {
        foreach (var file in fuImage.PostedFiles)
        {
            UploadFile("Images",fuImage);
        }
    }
    
}
```

And there is a method which I use to upload/save-as the file into folder as like this:

```
private void UploadFile(string FolderName, FileUpload fu)
{
    string FolderPath = "~\\" + FolderName;

    DirectoryInfo FolderDir = new DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath(FolderPath));
    if (!FolderDir.Exists)
    {
        FolderDir.Create();
    }

    string FilePath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath(FolderPath), fu.FileName);
    if (!File.Exists(FilePath))
    {
        fu.SaveAs(FilePath);
    }
}
```

The problem that I'm facing is - only one image file is uploads instead of uploading all images as like:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an error in your code. Here is a fixed code.

First make sure that you build the page on `asp.net 4.5` or newer

**web.config**

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.1" urlLinePragmas="true"/>
```

Next your `.cs`.

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (fuImage.HasFiles)
    {
        foreach (HttpPostedFile file in fuImage.PostedFiles) //be explicit
        //Note that var file is HttpPostedFile
        {
            UploadFile("Images",file); //not fuImage
        }
    }
}

private void UploadFile(string FolderName, HttpPostedFile fu)//FileUpload gives single file
{
    string FolderPath = "~/" + FolderName; // \\ is not the best choice
    //your remaining code works and is skipped for brevity

}
```